C# google sheets API Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
I'm trying to read and write Values from google sheets using google sheets API I'm able to Read and can't write values using update method, I'm getting the following error "Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]"
  private static UserCredential Login2(string googleclientid, string googleclientsecret, string[] scopes)
        {
            ClientSecrets sectets = new ClientSecrets()
            {
                ClientId = googleclientid,
                ClientSecret = googleclientsecret
            };
            return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(sectets, scopes, user: "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
        }
        static string[] scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };

  public void WriteValue(string spreadsheetId)
        {
            

            // How the input data should be interpreted.
            string valueInputOption = "RAW";  

            // The new values to apply to the spreadsheet.
            List<ValueRange> data = new List<ValueRange>(); // Instanciate a list of type ValueRange
            ValueRange values = new ValueRange(); // Instanciate a ValueRange object
            values.Range = "A1:B2"; // The range you want to update
            List<object> firstRow = new List<object> { "Hello", 2 };
            List<object> secondRow = new List<object> { 3, "Hey!" };
            // Populate the values to be inserted in the sheet
            values.Values = new List<IList<object>> { firstRow, secondRow };
            // add values to the data ValueRange List
            data.Add(values);

            // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
            BatchUpdateValuesRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
            requestBody.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;
            requestBody.IncludeValuesInResponse = true;
            requestBody.Data = data;
            using (var sheetservice = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = _userCredential }))
            {
                // Build and make the request
                SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchUpdateRequest request
                = sheetservice.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId);
                BatchUpdateValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
            }
        }

